# Calling jquery plugin in React not working but working in my console

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript, jquery-plugins

I just installed the jquery-slimscroll plugin in React and when I run

```
$('.sk-hits-grid-hit').eq(1).slimScroll({
    height: '26em'
  });
```

In my console, it works as expected, but it won't run in my application. It doesn't give me any errors in my application, it just doesn't do anything. I also checked the 'Network' tab in developer tools and all the files imported correctly.

This is my index.html:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
</head>
...
```

This is my index.tsx:

```
var $ = require("jquery");
import 'jquery-waypoints/waypoints.min.js';  //Waypoints trigger functions when you scroll to an element
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';             //Allows jQuery functionality
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';    //Front-end framework to help display webpage
import 'jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js';

...

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.sk-hits-grid-hit').eq(1).slimScroll({
      height: '26em'
    });
})
```

Any ideas? I tried moving my scripts to my body tags and there was no change.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a reference issue, try changing the path to the second reference:

```
"node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"
```

About as much as I can suggest without knowing your file path